# Using WebSphere's API to access the OperatingSystem

Tags: logging, filesystems, websphere

I want to write a software that unifies logs from different servers, all WebSphere, all from the same cell. The idea is to get a description one log that describes an entire system - composed of different servers.

In order to achieve this I need (Or so I think I need. Other suggestion will be welcomed) to access those servers operating systems and download the log files. I thought of a few things:
- Gain access via ssh
- Write a small aaplication, that accesses these files, and then sends it to the main log server in any form I wish.

However, what I really want is something that uses the WebSphere abilities and perhaps allows me access to the file system somehow. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way would be to write your jul log appender and redirect logs to your appender.

Anyway there are both free and commercial programs which do exact same thing you described.